# How can I use the DirectoryServices.Protocols.AuthType library and Negotiate AuthType with Novell?

Tags: .net-core, ldap, directoryservices, sasl, novell

I am currently working on an LDAP connection.
The code is using the `DirectoryServices` library, and I would like to only use the Novell library. I already replaced all the requests and connections by the right ones.
Now I am stuck because I don't now how to define my authentication type. In particular I would like to use a "negotiate" authentication protocol

Here is an example of what I would like to change :

```
using (var connection = new LdapConnection(identifier, credential, AuthMethod))
{
    connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
    if (!NoSigning && ((AuthMethod == AuthType.Kerberos) || (AuthMethod == AuthType.Negotiate)))
    {
        connection.SessionOptions.Sealing = true;
        connection.SessionOptions.Signing = true;
    }
}
```

In this code, my connection is an `LdapConnection` from the `DirectoryServices` library. I want to use the `Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapConnection` instead.
When I do this, the `AuthType` attribute doesn't exist, and neither does the `SessionOptions` attribute.

Thanks for your help !